# Is MongoDB Clustering / horizontal scaling free?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, influxdb

I'm looking for a NoSQL Database for an on premise deployement. It needs to be free for horizontal scaling (Clustering).

I was looking at influxdb which apparently is not free.

What about MongoDB? Couldn't find this info in their website.

Answer (score 1):

Community edition is free to run and supports sharding.